# Retrofit migration to 2.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2, structural-search

While migrating to Retrofit it's a nightmare to remove all service calls containing callbacks. I made use of Structural Search and Replace, but i've  to repeat templates due to varied number of arguments for a method call. My templates are as follows,

Search template

```
$MethodType$ $methodName$(
    $paramtype1$ $param1$,
    $paramtype2$ $param2$,
    Callback<$type$> callback);
```

Replace template

```
Call<$type$> $methodName$(
    $paramtype1$ $param1$,
    $paramtype2$ $param2$);
```

I used number fo parameters to address all service call we have. Was wondering if there is any way to write a search template that would find all methods that has "Callback callback" as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use a search template like this

```
$MethodType$ $methodName$($paramtype$ $param$, Callback<$type$> $callback$);
```

Click `Edit Variables...` and give `$param$` an Occurrences count of `0,∞`. This will find all methods with a last parameter of type `Callback` and zero or more other parameters.

Use the following replacement template

```
Call<$type$> $methodName$($paramtype$ $param$);
```